# Close external application launched from R

Tags: r, windows, shellexecute

Is it possible to close an application that was launched from within R?

Assume that I have opened a CSV file `my_file.csv` with its associated application [via the `shell.exec` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/shell.exec). I then want to close this application.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "I have opened the file with R"?

Comment: @AEF I have opened the file without R (by double clicking on the file). Now, I want to close it from within R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since R has no control over other programs you cannot directly close files opended without R reliably. You do not even know which program to close. E.g. one one computer a csv file may be opened with notepad, on another computer it may be opened with Excel.

If you know the program you can use `system2()` or similar commands to execute a command to kill the other program. E.g. if you want to close Excel execute `system2("taskkill", args = "/im excel.exe")`. Note that this will close all open instances of the program/Excel, not jut a specific one.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have opened the csv file with Excel in Windows 10. Is there a possibility to close the file within R if I know this?

Comment: I adapted my answer to show how to terminate a program in windows.

Comment: Thanks, that already helps a lot! Is it somehow possible to close only the file `my_file.csv`, but keep other excel files opened? Unfortunately, I didn't find anything helpful in the R help documentation of system2.

Comment: No, it is not possible to close Excel from R at all; `taskkill` is a windows command. So you won't find anything in R documentation. What you can do, is writing a small windows program that communicates with Excel through the COM interface and call that program from R with `system2`.